# Form submit is not working in custom module

Tags: 8, forms

I’ve build several custom modules which connect to webservices.

They  works fine except one where i need to validate a form.

If i execute the function inside controller (without the need to validate the form), the datas are sent so i can say the php is ok.

My problem is the form button is not working.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
```

or

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Valider</button>
```

doesn’t submit the form in **front-end** (and doesn’t reload the page).

I’ve read topics on this and solution seem to do something like :

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {  

$form['submit'] = [  
'#type' => 'submit',  
'#value' => t('Submit'),  
];  

return $form;  
}
```

But i don’t how to do since the "controler class return" is :

```
output = array();

        $output['dc'] = array(
            '#markup' => $tableau,
            '#allowed_tags' => ['table', 'caption', 'thead', 'tbody', 'input', 'thead', 'tr', 'td', 'th', 'label', 'p', 'h2', 'button', 'radio', 'div'],
            '#attached' => array(
                'library' => array(
                    'webservices_xxx/bootstrap.bootstrap-datepicker'
                ),
            ),
        );
        return $output;
```

ps : i know, `allowed_tags` is a bit uggly here but i don’t know for now how to use `#type` or `#theme`, that would be an other question.

Actually, i use  `'#markup' => $tableau`, because i have a form but also somes tables.

Comment: Are you trying to put a custom HTML form into Drupal's form API? It won't work, you need to build the form with the form API in PHP. Just like the `buildForm` method you've seen

Comment: @Clive Yes, i’m trying to create a form inside some html generated by a custom module. It’s not possible ? I’ve read about the form API but since i have to generates some tables (other webservices) so i was thinking form API was only able to generate a form. Also, form API works in frontend ?

Comment: You can theme any aspect of a FAPI form, that's definitely the right approach to take. Drupal won't stop you using a form you've put together manually, but everything (build, render, validation, submission, etc) needs to be coded manually by you, and you might find yourself fighting with something else Drupal is doing. You get a lot of functionality for very little effort by using the API, I'd recommend it

Comment: If you want to have custom HTML for form elements, that is doable, but you cannot drop raw HTML code of a form into twig templates and do much. Drupal won't know anything is going on, and you lose access to pretty much 100% of the API.

Comment: Thank. It was finally easy to create forms with FAPI and i understand now why it should be used (really easy to build, validate and submit). I’ve followed this introduction to Form API : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api Should I answer my own question, delete it or can you answer it as you are more a Drupal expert than me. I'll vote for it.